# What is the point of a higher order function?

Tags: javascript

Why do I see higher-order functions being used in a lot of code? It seems like to me it is almost the same exact thing as a regular function only that with a normal function you can just return what you need, **just like what returning a 2nd function does, it ends up returning a value in the end anyways but now you just had to write more code**.

I've read this guide (source: [link](https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-functions)) and here the guy went from this:

```
function getAttribute(attr) {
    return typeof this.getAttribute(attr) != 'undefined';
}

var accessors = {
    sortable: {
        get: function() {
            return getAttribute('sortable');
        }
    },
    droppable: {
        get: function() {
            return getAttribute('droppable');
        }
    }
};
```

to this:

```
function generateGetMethod(attr) {
    return function() {
        return typeof this.getAttribute(attr) != 'undefined';
    };
}

var accessors = {
    sortable: {
        get: generateGetMethod('sortable')
    },
    droppable: {
        get: generateGetMethod('droppable')
    }
};
```

A quote from that link above states in the end: "This is a really useful technique that saves you from repeating likewise code and, when used correctly, is easy to understand and maintain!"

To me it confuses me because why is the function returning another function when I can either just assign the returning function into a separate variable, or just use a normal function with an extra argument?

Here is a normal function:

```
function water(userArg) {
  return {
    water: userArg
  };
}
console.log(water('is liquid')); // returns: { water: 'is liquid' }
```

Here is a higher order function:

```
function water() {
  return function (valueOfWater) {
    return {
      water: valueOfWater
    };
  };
}
console.log(water()('is liquid')); // returns: { water: 'is liquid' }
```

They both return the same thing. What powerful concept am I missing?

Comment: I think you should test your examples, they don't return what you claim they do.

Comment: My bad. Just added some more key strokes and fixed it. Went from `console.log(water('is liquid'))` to `console.log(water()('is liquid'))`

Comment: What's so confusing about "*saves you from repeating likewise code*"?

Comment: In the example above it doesn't look that it is actually helping much. Maybe you'll bump into another example where you'll understand why people use such _higher functions_.

Comment: Its confusing how just "saves you from repeating  likewise code" makes higher order functions being used in almost every module like its a godly javascript feature.

Comment: @Chris Can you tell us why in your example you have not used `console.log({water:'is liquid'})`? That does the same and is even shorter, and doesn't need any function at all. So why do we use functions?

Comment: One of the regular usecases of higher order functions is, e.g. if you use [*closures*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(computer_programming)) to pass concrete functions as a callback. With this you have the possibility to have values passed to a function, that you will call later from another part of your software, that would not have access to those values.

Comment: @Chris well higher-order functions *are* a godly abstraction (though not limited to JS at all)

Comment: Here's an example that makes a little more sense -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/6h3r3fw5/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When assigning a normal function to a variable,

```
function getAttribute(attr) {
    return typeof this.getAttribute(attr) != 'undefined';
}

var x = getAttribute(attr);
```

then `x` is going to be the *value that the function returns*. Nothing special here.

However, the power of higher-order functions is evident here:

```
function generateGetMethod(attr) {
    return function() {
        return typeof this.getAttribute(attr) != 'undefined';
    };
}
var y = generateGetMethod(attr);
```

In this case, `y` is actually equal to a **function**, and can be called with different parameters, such as `y(attributeA);` and so on. In other words, the higher-order function in this case acts sort of like a generator, or factory method. It creates general functions that can be applied.